# Resource containing information on android xml tags, attriutes and schema

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently learning android development and it seems like there's always some new xml attribute popping up at every turn and I'm having a hard time keeping up.

I need to know if there is some kind of knowledge base or resource containing detailed information on the different AVAILABLE android schema and xml tags and attributes in each one that I'll encounter as an android developer.

Comment: developer.android.com.  Each class document details the XML attributes.

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot about that